STM32F407 DFU problem in App Verification place on memory
I'm working with the DFU for the STM32F407 y I'm try to understand the application exist verification. Added to this, I need to use the emulated EEPROM to know if it run the DFU to remote update or run de application.
In some examples that I can find, all use the next code:
    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(boot1_GPIO_Port, boot1_Pin ) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
    {
        /* Test if user code is programmed starting from address 0x08008000 */
        if (((*(__IO uint32_t *) USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD) & 0x2FFC0000) == 0x20000000)
        {

            /* Jump to user application */
            JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t *) (USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD + 4);
            JumpToApplication = (pFunction) JumpAddress;

            /* Initialize user application's Stack Pointer */
            __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t *) USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD);
            JumpToApplication();
        }
    }

This example use a button, but I'm going to replace it with check of an value on emulated EEPROM.
Reading many posts, I'm more confused. I have the DFU and the emulated EEPROM in the beginning (0-7FFF DFU, 8000-FFFF Emulated EEPROM) so, the start position for the application is in 10000. Why I can't veryfied if the app exist only cheking if the start position is not cleared (0xFFFF FFFF)? How can I do this, if in nowhere place explain how to create the mask (of the example)?
I was make many compilations with different positions of application on memory, to try to understand the mask o trying to find the logic. I was use the 0x08000000 standar, with one example in 0x08008000 or another in 0x0800C000 and, finally, my project in 0x08010000, but nothing. I can understand the logic for this check.
